# Selenium+Docker timing out

Tags: ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, docker-compose, selenium-chromedriver

Im'm receiving a time out error and inspecting the chrome driver log I found this:

```
{
  "traceId": "c6aa7643e1e8cde422b9a0eb763fa56c",
  "eventTime": 1710077257942652356,
  "eventName": "exception",
  "attributes": {
    "driver.url": "http://localhost:42786",
    "exception.message": "Error while creating session with the driver service. Stopping driver service: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
  (Driver info: chromedriver=102.0.5005.61 (0e59bcc00cc4985ce39ad31c150065f159d95ad3-refs/branch-heads/5005@{#819}),platform=Linux 6.5.0-25-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 61.70 seconds
Build info: version: '4.2.2', revision: '683ccb65d6'
System info: host: '6d6562c74135', ip: '*ip redacted*', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.5.0-25-generic', java.version: '11.0.15'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown",
    "exception.stacktrace": "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
  (Driver info: chromedriver=102.0.5005.61 (0e59bcc00cc4985ce39ad31c150065f159d95ad3-refs/branch-heads/5005@{#819}),platform=Linux 6.5.0-25-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 61.70 seconds
Build info: version: '4.2.2', revision: '683ccb65d6'
System info: host: '6d6562c74135', ip: '*ip redacted*', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.5.0-25-generic', java.version: '11.0.15'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:217)
\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:169)
\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:54)
\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$3(ProtocolHandshake.java:151)
\tat java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
\tat java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
\tat java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
\tat java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
\tat java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
\tat java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
\tat java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
\tat java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
\tat java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:543)
\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:153)
\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:102)
\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:67)
\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.config.DriverServiceSessionFactory.apply(DriverServiceSessionFactory.java:141)
\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.config.DriverServiceSessionFactory.apply(DriverServiceSessionFactory.java:67)
\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.local.SessionSlot.apply(SessionSlot.java:145)
\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.local.LocalNode.newSession(LocalNode.java:362)
\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.NewNodeSession.execute(NewNodeSession.java:52)
\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$TemplatizedRoute.handle(Route.java:192)
\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:68)
\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.security.RequiresSecretFilter.lambda$apply$0(RequiresSecretFilter.java:64)
\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.tracing.SpanWrappedHttpHandler.execute(SpanWrappedHttpHandler.java:86)
\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute(Filter.java:64)
\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle(Route.java:336)
\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:68)
\tat org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.Node.execute(Node.java:240)
\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle(Route.java:336)
\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:68)
\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.AddWebDriverSpecHeaders.lambda$apply$0(AddWebDriverSpecHeaders.java:35)
\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorFilter.lambda$apply$0(ErrorFilter.java:44)
\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute(Filter.java:64)
\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorFilter.lambda$apply$0(ErrorFilter.java:44)
\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute(Filter.java:64)
\tat org.openqa.selenium.netty.server.SeleniumHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(SeleniumHandler.java:44)
\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
",
    "exception.type": "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException",
    "logger": "org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.config.DriverServiceSessionFactory",
    "session.capabilities": "{\"goog:chromeOptions\": {\"w3c\": false,\"args\": [  \"--window-size=1280,1024\",  \"--user-agent=Selenium Test Browser\",  \"--allowed-ips=*ip redacted*\",  \"--disable-dev-shm-usage\"  ]  },  \"se:noVncPort\": 7900,  \"browserName\": \"chrome\",  \"platformName\": \"ANY\",  \"platform\": \"ANY\",  \"se:vncEnabled\": true  }
"
  }
}
```

First I tried to run the script using `php-cli` but I still got the same error, then I added the `--disable-dev-shm-usage` argument because I have read in another post, a similar problem was resolved with this. Finally I added `--allowed-ips` argument since in the log I found `Only local connections are allowed.` and searching online I have read I needed to specify my IP to bypass this restriction.

The VPS setup is very basic Ubuntu with selenium+docker. Below is the `docker-compose.yml` file in use:

```
version: "3"
services:
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:4.7.2-20221219
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443

  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox:4.7.2-20221219
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
      
  edge:
    image: selenium/node-edge:4.7.2-20221219
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443

  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:4.7.2-20221219
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4442:4442"
      - "4443:4443"
      - "4444:4444"
```